# Python chat server

Tags: python

i am a basic/new python programmer. I am trying to create a chat server that connects via Telnet. My code is running well(I think) and it wont let me connect when i try to connect through cmd. does anyone know why this error could occur as it says 'connection failed'. By the way this is the code i am using;

```
import sys #imports system
import socket #imports socket features
from _thread import  *

host = '' #sets host to your IP 
port = 5555 #Connects to any port
s =socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try: #runs the connection
    s.bind((host, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

s.listen(5) #listens for a queue of 5
print ('Waiting for a connection...')
def threaded_client(conn): #each time someone makes a connection it will pass them through a threaded client
    conn.send(str.encode('Welcome, type your info\n'))

    while True: #giving a server output to all users
        data =conn.recv(2048)
        reply = 'Server Output: '+data.decode(uft-8)
        if not data:
            break
        conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
    conn.close()

while True:

    conn, addr = s.accept() #connecting to address and accepts
    print ('Connected to: '+addr[0]+':'+str(addr[1])) #just some additional information that the user will see.

    start_new_thread(threaded_client,(conn,))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to connect from your local network or by remote?
If you are trying to connect from a remote machine you should port forward the port 5555, the router might be blocking your connection.

Comment: i am using cmd and typing 'telnet localhost 5555'